# Need help using all() and find() in the same function for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my layouts, I am displaying all the categories (from my database) using a foreach statement. In the page, it is a page is it shown from the show() function. It seems a little contradicting because I have to use all() for the layout, and find() in the page. Is there any way to work around this?

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $categories = category::find($id);
        $products = product::all()->sortBy('ID');
        $categories = category::all()->sortBy('ID');
        return view('categories', compact('products','categories'));
    }
```

In the template

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
  <li class="text-uppercase" style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="{{ route('category.show', $category->id) }}">{{ $category->name}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

In the page itself ( **localhost:8000/category/5** ) I just want to display the name of the category in the page, not display all like in the above code block.

```
{{ $categories->name}}
```

When I put both the all() and find() into the same function

This is the error message:-

Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:.............\resources\views\categories.blade.php)

Comment: You forgot to pass `$category` to your view, pay attention to the variable names `$category` and `$categories`

Comment: @RyanLim can you show this with code **When I put both the all() and find() into the same function**

Comment: @Neverever
I don't quite get you, if I edit the {{ $categories->name }} into {{ $category->name }} then there's an error stating:

Undefined variable: category (View: C:\....\..\...\...\resources\views\categories.blade.php)

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Look at the function at the top, that is what I meant. There is a find() and all() in the same function for categories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is you've been overwritten your `$categories` variable. Once you populate it with single category (via `find()`) then you override it with all categories (via `all()`).

You should override your `show()` function

```
public function show($id)
    {

        $category = category::find($id);
        $products = product::all()->sortBy('ID');
        $categories = category::all()->sortBy('ID');
        return view('categories', compact('products','categories', 'category'));
    }
```

You should use `$categories` variable to get all categories and use `$category` for getting a single category.